# Returning table name and schema name along with column values

Tags: postgresql, select, schema, insert, table

I have table in SQL:

**public.employee**

| name | age |
| --- | --- |
| abc | 20 |
| xyz | 30 |

I want a query which would return the column values along with schema name and table name.

Input:

```
select * from public.employee
```

Output:

| name | age | schema_name | table_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

The reason for doing this is, I want to have an aggregate info table which has count for each schema and table.

Answer (score 2):

You can display the table name in the result using the system column `tableoid` that is available in every table.

```
select *, tableoid::regclass::text as table_name
from public.employee;
```

This will however only display the fully qualified name if the table's schema is **not** in the `search_path`. If the table's schema **is** in the search_path, only the table name will be shown.